# auto generation of html report in pytest without commanline arguments

Tags: report, pytest, pytest-html

I am using pytest-html plugin.
When arguments is passed in command line html report is generated.
Need to create html report automatically and the html report link should be displayed in terminal.

Answer (score 4):

You can put the cmdline argument in the `pytest.ini` file in the root directory

```
$ cat pytest.ini
[pytest]
addopts = --html=report.html --self-contained-html
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by writing the `pytest_cmdline_preparse()` hook in the file `conftest.py`

```py
def pytest_cmdline_preparse(config, args):
    html_file = func_to_generate_html_filename()
    print('HTML report file:', html_file)
    args.extend(['--html', html_file, '--self-contained-html'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative option, just like Nizar's answer

```
def pytest_cmdline_preparse(config, args):
    config.option.htmlpath = "my-report.html"
    config.option.self_contained_html = True
```